# Invalid or corupt jarfile

Tags: java, jar, corrupt

I tried to create a jar file from a java project, which uses some external jars. I created a lib folder and put all the jars I need there.

I run the project in eclipse by adding all the jars in the lib folder to the Build Path and it works ok.

When I try to create the jar with ant from build.xml, it seems ok, no error is shown.

When I try to run the jar, I get the message "Invalid or corupt jarfile".

In build.xml:
I define the path to use for compiling:

```
<path id="project.classpath">  
     <fileset dir="${lib}">
         <include name="**/*.jar"/>
     </fileset>
</path>
```

This is the target for the compilation:

```
<target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source " >
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}">  
          <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>  
    </javac>  
</target>
```

And this is the target for making the jar file:

```
<target name="dist" depends="compile" description="generate the distribution" >
      <mkdir dir="${dist}"/>
      <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar file -->
      <jar jarfile="${dist}/MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar" basedir="${build}"> 
          <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main}" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path:" value="lib/**/*.*"/>
          </manifest>
          <fileset dir="${src}" includes="images/**/*.*" />
       </jar>
       <echo file="${dist}/start.bat" message="java -jar MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar" />
  </target>
```

Can you please tell me what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First remove the colon after `Class-Path:` to match

```
<attribute name="Class-Path" value="lib/**/*.*"/>
```

Then I suggest reading

[HOWTO Create MANIFEST.MF Classpath From Ant](http://martin.ankerl.com/2005/11/30/howto-create-manifestmf-classpath-from-ant/) or better using [Manifestclasspath](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifestclasspath.html)

Comment: It worked with the manifestclasspath. The problem was indeed that the jar names were way too long than the 72 characters allowed.

Comment: Lines in MANIFEST.MF are wrappable.   I too think the culprit is the extra colon.

Comment: +1 for the Manifestclasspath.  Haven't looked at the new goodies since 1.6.2, so this is a nice addition.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your Class-Path attribute should have a trailing colon specified in your `build.xml`.

Try using

```
jar tvf {jarname}
```

from the command line, and see if that can expand your jar file, and whether it contains what you expect (the above will simply dump the table of contents, but is a useful check)

EDIT: Changed to reflect the feedback below

Comment: I also tried this version:
<attribute name="Class-Path:" value="lib/**/*.jar"/>
 And still didn't work

Comment: If you look in your manifest file, you'll see that written in. But are the classes actually in your .jar file ?

Comment: I opened the jar and it seemed to include everyting. At least all the classes and files in the project.

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.0
Created-By: 11.0-b15 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: controller.Client
Class-Path:: lib/**/*.jar

Comment: Yes, the classes are in the jars included.

Comment: Note the double colon in Class-Path

Comment: If I don't inlude the Class Path in the manifest file, then I get the exception NoClassDeffFoundError

Comment: Brian, you were right. The colod was the problem. Now I get the NoClassDefFoundError. I search the jar for that class and it's there. I also use some other classes in the application (before the one which generates the problem) from the same jar and I get no exception.

Do you have any ideea why is this happening?

Comment: You may want to check that classes referenced IN the class that you're getting the NoClassDefFound error are also there. Otherwise the class can't be loaded/constructed properly.

Comment: They are there. By the way, is there a problem if I use threads in those classes?